# How to install app from git repository via docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I want to download my app from a git repo and install it on docker. But I cannot install git.

```
sudo docker images
```

prints

> REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED    VIRTUAL SIZE
>
> ubuntu              15.04               216c11b99bd0     9 days ago          116.8 MB
>
> ubuntu              vivid               216c11b99bd0        9 days ago          116.8 MB
>
> ...

```
sudo docker run ubuntu apt-get install -y git
```

creates a long [log](http://pastebin.com/eSMwXtrp)

```
sudo docker run ubuntu git status
```

returns

```
2014/12/14 13:46:05 exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
```

When I try to install git again, the system doesn't notice that it has already been installed. With image id is used instead of "ubuntu" result is the same

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is running another container with the second command: `sudo docker run ubuntu git status` which by definition will be a fresh image.

What you might want is to use the [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec) command (docker 1.3):

```
sudo docker exec <option> [container-id] <command>

Options: <option>
  -d, --detach=false         Detached mode: run command in the background
  -i, --interactive=false    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
  -t, --tty=false            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

Comment: `docker exec -it geo2tag git status
Error: Command not found: exec
Error: Command not found: -it
Usage: docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND [arg...]
 -H=[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]: tcp://host:port to bind/connect to or unix://path/to/socket to use
`

Comment: My bad, fixed the answer, you might want to use -d with exec.

Comment: It doesn't find `exec` itself. `docker exec -d c4b12 git status
Error: Command not found: exec
Error: Command not found: -d`

Comment: which version of docker are you on. This works with docker 1.3

Comment: client & server: 1.01 client&server API's: 1.12

Comment: Doesn't work. I used `docker ps -l`, then `docker commit` on the returned id and then used it as image. You may add it to response.

Comment: There is a fundamental misunderstanding of how docker works by the OP.   Try going through this:  https://www.docker.com/tryit/   And updating your docker to the latest version.

Comment: The solution is from this tutorial, actually. `docker run learn/tutorial echo "hello world"`

Comment: `exec` was added in docker 1.3

Answer (score 0):

As nash_ag correctly pointed out, every time you do `docker run ... ubuntu` you create a new, independent container based on the `ubuntu` image. The easiest way for you to getWhen you need git to get your application, you usually create a new image which wound contain git (see http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#creating-our-own-images).